# Why do Arc and Mutex allow me to change the value of an immutable variable?

Tags: rust

Take this example:

```
fn main() {
    let dato = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(1u8));

    for _ in 0..3 {
        let value = dato.clone();

        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            let v = value.lock().unwrap();
            *v += 1; // <- Error
        });
    }

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1u64));

    println!("{:?}", dato);
}
```

> cannot borrow immutable local variable `v` as mutable

I know that changing to `mut` works:

```
std::thread::spawn(move || {
    let mut v = value.lock().unwrap();
    *v += 1;
});
```

but why does this work:

```
let value = dato.clone();

std::thread::spawn(move || {
    *value.lock().unwrap() += 1;    
});
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=401b3f61be43bb67ea30562ae568fc19&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Update : I looked and I think it has to do with the use of std::cell inside Mutex -> UnsafeCell https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html but I do not know if it's really, this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`value.lock().unwrap()` returns a value of type [`MutexGuard`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html), which has a `DerefMut` implementation:

```
impl<'mutex, T: ?Sized> DerefMut for MutexGuard<'mutex, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T { ... }
}
```

`DerefMut::deref_mut(x)` is equivalent to `&mut *x`; naturally, `DerefMut` is also used for assignments under the pointer, like in your case.

Therefore, for `*v += 1` to work, `v` should be a `mut` variable - otherwise it would be impossible for `DerefMut::deref_mut` to be invoked at all.

`*value.lock().unwrap() += 1` works because now `value.lock().unwrap()` is a temporary variable without an explicit binding, so Rust is free to assign its mutability automatically.

The fact that `Mutex` contains an `UnsafeCell` inside is not related to this particular thing about `DerefMut` directly; however, it does mean that `Mutex` provides something called *internal mutability*, i.e. it allows one to mutate its contents through a shared reference. You can read more on it [in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I recently read about std::cell:: * and see in the code, UnsafeCell, I think I was perhaps related in some way, thanks for your explanation.